# PHP: Check is null was passed as a parameter or assigned as the default

Tags: php

I'm trying to write my object members so they can be accessed with the format:

```
$object->member() // Returns current value of member
$object->member($new_value) // Sets value of member to $new_value
```

Here's an example of my implementation:

```
class Automobile
{
    private $color;
    private $make;
    private $model;

    public function __construct($inColor, $inMake, $inModel) {
        $this->color($inColor);
        $this->make($inMake);
        $this->model($inModel);
    }

    private function gset($p, $v) {
        if ($v) {
            $this->{$p} = $v;
            return $this;
        } else {
            return $this->{$p};
        }
    }

    public function color($v = null) {
        return $this->gset(__FUNCTION__, $v);
    }
    public function make($v = null) {
        return $this->gset(__FUNCTION__, $v);
    }
    public function model($v = null) {
        return $this->gset(__FUNCTION__, $v);
    }
}
```

The effect I'm looking for is:

```
$car = new Automobile('Red', 'Honda', 'Civic');

var_dump($car->color()); // Returns Red
$car->color('Blue'); // Sets color to Blue
var_dump($car->color()); // Returns Blue
```

Everything works great as is, HOWEVER I'd like to also be able to literally pass `null` to the function so it will insert `null` as the value, but since the default of the parameter is `null` also it will only return the current value:

```
$car->color(null); // Would like to insert null as car color, but this is obviously equivalent to $car->color()
var_dump($car->color()); // Returns Blue
```

Is there anyway to know if a value is the result of the actual parameter being passed or the result of using the default value?  I think my first opportunity to test is inside the function itself, and by then it's already set either way.

Any other thoughts on how to achieve what I'm looking for?

I realize I can write a separate function to `null` a particular member, such as `$car->null_color()`, but at the moment I'm trying to squeeze it somehow into the same `$object->member()` format.

Comment: Hello,

since you test `$v` here

```php
if ($v) {
```
a `null` value will not be set, since the `null` will fail the `if` test

maybe you can create something like this
```php
private function gset($p, $v) {
        if ($v || $v === null) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I currently do that here: ```if ($v)```
@h3nr1ke, I can test there, but I still have no way to know if the ```null``` value is from the default of the previous function or if the user deliberately passed ```null``` to null the value.

Comment: Sounds simple enough to change the default value you are using to something else like maybe `($v = 'SomethingImpossible')`

Comment: It's kind of dangerous to put in $this->{$p} = $v; without some kind of validation what $p actually is.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, great suggestion, although I've adopted the ```func_num_args``` approach.

@bestprogrammerintheworld, I agree, but I'll build in the validation portion later.  I'm just trying to get this passing of the arguments down for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `func_num_args()` to determine if any arguments passed or not.

```
function color($c = null) {
    if(func_num_args() == 1) {
        $this->color = $c;
    }
    return $this->color;
}
```

Comment: Excellent.  ```func_num_args``` is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
public function color($v = null) {

    //If nothing or NULL is sent to this function 
    //return current color
    if ($v === null) return $this->color; 

    //Set color
    $this->color = $v;
}
```

Comment: How will you assign `null` to `$this->color` by your strategy?